# C++ std::thread makes segmentation fault error when it was used with SFML

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm trying to develop Multi-threaded game using SFML.
I compiled the code below from [SFML official website](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php).

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It worked well. The problem happened when I modified the code to use thread like below.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void Render(sf::RenderWindow& _window, sf::CircleShape& _shape)
{
    while (_window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (_window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                std::cout << "Closing window...\n";
                _window.close();
            }
        }

        _window.clear();
        _window.draw(_shape);
        _window.display();
    }
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    std::thread renderThread(Render, std::ref(window), std::ref(shape));

    renderThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me

> Segmentation fault

message on terminal when I close the window.

I want to know why this code gives me segmentation fault error and fix the error.

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: This may help: _This is an important limitation of most operating systems: the event loop (more precisely, the pollEvent or waitEvent function) must be called in the same thread that created the window._ (from [Opening and managing a SFML window](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php)). You created the window in main thread but called the polling in your thread function.

Comment: Thank you Scheff, G.M. . That was what I was looking for.